# QtCreator issues ld: warning: directory not found for vcpkg Qt

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt-creator, vcpkg

I installed Qt5 with vcpkg on macOS Catalina. And installed QtCreator using the online installer.

Then on QtCreatpr, Preferences, Kits, Qt Versions I added qmake from both

```
/Users/user/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/tools/qt5/bin
/Users/user/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/tools/qt5/debug/bin
```

It seems to be working fine but there is one thing, when building a project it returns

```
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/user/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/debug/lib/manual-link'
```

What is that warning telling me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is that warning telling me?

Just that the directory `/Users/user/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/debug/lib/manual-link` does not exist. If you want to get rid of the error just create the folder itself. vcpkg is probably manually adding it somewhere without checking if it actually exists.