# Qt from vcpkg on apple M1 - ld: warning: directory not found for option

Tags: macos, qt, ld, qmake, vcpkg

This is related to [Object file was built for newer OSX version than being linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216273/object-file-was-built-for-newer-osx-version-than-being-linked/75437656#75437656)

Here on macOS Monterey M1 macbook, I'm using Qt5.15.6 from vcpkg. On [qmake](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-variable-reference.html) project I add

```
CONFIG+=sdk_no_version_check

QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 12.0
```

And it seems I can build/run a Qt project. There is a minor issue though, at the end of build it prints

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option 'L/Users/user/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/debug/lib/manual-link'
```

What is this warning about? How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QtCreator issues ld: warning: directory not found for vcpkg Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71948575/qtcreator-issues-ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-vcpkg-qt)

Answer (score 0):

```
CONFIG += sdk_no_version_check
QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 12.0

#QMAKE_APPLE_DEVICE_ARCHS = arm64

CONFIG -= debug_and_release debug_and_release_target
```

And remember to use Qt kit from vcpkg, not Qt kit installed with Qt online installer.